# Print nicely formatted numpy array with complex and / or real elements (real_if_close)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format

After 2 hours of playing Whack-A-Mole I'm giving up: I'd like to print out nicely the results of an FFT, suppressing all the "nearly" real-valued elements created by numerical inaccuracies.

First attempt:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.arange(10)
x = np.sin(np.pi * n / 5)
X = np.fft.fft(x)

print(np.real_if_close(X))
```

This doesn't work; I guess the imaginary parts are only suppressed if ALL elements are "nearly" real (otherwise the data types in the array wouldn't be identical). Is this correct?

The next attempt using a loop works, but the formatting is ugly:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(np.real_if_close(X[i]))
```

So I tried to use print formatting:

```
for i in range(10):
   print("{0:5.5g}".format(X[i]))
```

It works but now the small imaginary parts are back. Trying to combine both attempts fails with the infamous "`non-empty format string passed to object.__format__`" error (I'm using Python 3.5):

```
for i in range(10):
    print("{0:g}".format(np.real_if_close(X[i])))
```

Can somebody explain this behaviour? And maybe suggest a solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is type-defined (dtype), so if you have a numpy array with only one complex value, the type will be complex and thus ALL the values are stored as complex number.

If it's just to print out values, you should use lists instead of numpy array or simply a loop. The X2 list gives the home made solution. If you really want to use real_if_close, then you should use numpy.asscalar to convert the type numpy.array to a scalar value that format ":g" understand.

```
X = [1+1e-14j,1+1e-13j]
eps = np.finfo(float).eps
tol = 100 # tolerance (used in real_if_close)

X2 = [np.real(x) if np.imag(x)<tol*eps else x for x in X]
X3 = [np.asscalar(np.real_if_close(x)) for x in X]

for x in X3:
    print("{:.5g}".format(x))
```

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion! My data comes as a numpy array, numpy operations (like np.real or np.real_if_close) return numpy data types. That's why I ruled out lists. What do you mean by "using a look"?

Still, I'd like to understand the "non-empty format string passed to object.__format__" error message and why I'm getting it in only one of the cases described above.

Comment: look is a typo I meant "loop". Now the error you get is because np.real_if_close returns a numpy.array and not a complex nor a float so format don't know how to process it. I have updated my script so that now you have a new list X2 with what you want. Then you can use format with ":g" for every values

Comment: My previous comment explain why it doesn't work. I have now updated my solution to show you how to solve it. Just use np.asscalar to comvert a numpy.array in a scalar value that format understand.